# Issue in setting date using calendar

Tags: java, datetime, calendar

I am trying to set the date as DEC 31,2012 using the following snippet ,but i am getting Mar 03,2013,what is wrong here.

```
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
today.set(Calendar.MONTH, 13);
today.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);
today.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2012);

long calendarNeverEndDate = today.getTime().getTime();
System.out.println("calendarNeverEndDate:"
                   + sdf.formatLocal(calendarNeverEndDate));
```

Answer (score 5):

That's because months are 0-indexed (yes, it's inconsistent with days :-( ).

**edit:** As Romain mentioned, it's better to use constants

```java
Calendar.DECEMBER
```

Comment: Ah, Java dates! Pass in an invalid value, it'll let it though and behave in unpredictable ways. And "valid" values are often counter-intuitive... *sigh*. BTW, you should mention that using `Calendar.DECEMBER` is probably safer.